# AT job won’t run script but script runs if pasted to command line

Tags: php, sh, at-command

I have these three files to notify my email list whenever I post to a blog:
“functionality_plugin.php”— contains new_post_notify() which creates—>

“run_email_processor.sh” in the html folder and sets an AT job on the server to run it.—>

“run_email_processor.sh” touches “email_processor.php” on the server which constructs an email using the arguments from the .sh script. It loops through a list of emails sending the constructed email to each address. It also writes a log file in the same directory of all addresses emailed.

THE PROBLEM 
The “run_email_processor.sh” in the AT job typically contains the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
php -f ../var/www/html/wp-admin/email_processor.php arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
```

If I paste the contents onto the command line and hit Enter, the downstream process behaves as expected, sending all emails.

However, if instead I let the AT job execute the script, nothing down stream happens.

-The AT job is owned by www-data:www-data.

-email_processor.php has full permissions set (for testing).

-the AT job reads as follows using atq :

```
45      Tue Feb 25 13:30:00 2020 a www-data
```

-Using at -c 45, I can view the contents of the AT job.

-As stated above, if I copy/paste the contents into the command line and run it, all works as expected.

THE QUESTION 
Why does it work when pasted to the command line but not when run from the AT job???

Comment: The environment in which the `at` job runs might not have `php` in its `PATH`, have you tried using the full path to it?

Comment: I have not but I will give that a shot right now. Thanks!

Comment: Benjamin W. — No change by using full path. I actually put the full path to php in the environment file a few days ago. So I reckon I should have expected that.

Comment: change this `../var/www/html/wp-admin/email_processor.php` with absolute path

Comment: That seems to be what worked! However, I also created a file “at.allow” and placed www-data in it. I had already removed www-data from the “at.deny” file. Thanks! I knew it was something utterly simple yet beyond my limited experience.