# AT job executes bash script if owner is root, but not if www-data

Tags: bash, permissions, at-command

If I set the following AT job as root user it works as expected:

```
at now +2 minutes -f /var/www/html/run_email_processor.sh
```

However, if I change to the www-data user via

```
su -s /bin/bash www-data
```

and set the same AT job, it will NOT execute the script.

I am setting the AT job programmatically from the web server. That makes the owner of the AT job www-data.

In web server Php script, is there a way to set the AT job programmatically as owner root instead of automatically as www-data?

Or somehow set www-data as being able to run the AT job script?

Any help or enlightenment would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE—-
As user www-data, I ran the *contents* of the run_email_processor.sh script and got the following error:

```
Could not open input file: ../var/www/html/wp-admin/email_processor.php
```

So it appears www-data can’t open the web server Php file but root can open it.

What do I need to do to let www-data open the Php file??

Thanks again!

Comment: So I created a file “at.allow” and placed www-data in it. Plus removed the two periods before the slash so the path would be absolute. Works now! Kudos to users at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402851/at-job-won-t-run-script-but-script-runs-if-pasted-to-command-line